# Java Timestamp Subtraction

Tags: java, json, timestamp, java-time

I have a timestamp as a String from a Json in the form of `11/02/2017 17:25:20` as actualArrivalTime and `11/02/2017 17:25:22` as actualScheduledTime. I would like to calculate delayTime by subtracting the two timestamps to get the difference, which will in this case be +2 or -2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to parse the strings into a date - in your case, the [`LocalDateTime` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) seems appropriate. You can then calculate the difference:

```
String actualArrivalTime = "11/02/2017 17:25:20";
String actualScheduledTime = "11/02/2017 17:25:22";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime arrival = LocalDateTime.parse(actualArrivalTime, fmt);
LocalDateTime scheduled = LocalDateTime.parse(actualScheduledTime, fmt);

long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(arrival, scheduled);
System.out.println("Time difference in seconds: " + seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var actualArrivalTime = new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:20");
var actualScheduledTime = new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:22");

var delayTime =  (actualArrivalTime - actualScheduledTime) / 1000; //-2
```

Depending on which order you need, you can switch the two vars around.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date1=new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:20");
var date2=new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:22");

var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
console.log(diff/1000);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask. Is this solution for java or JavaScript? I'm working on java...pulling data from a Json. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arrivalTime = new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:20");
var scheduledTime = new Date("11/02/2017 17:25:22");

var diff =  arrivalTime.getTime() - scheduledTime.getTime();
var diffInMs = (diff/1000);
```